# Large numbers of TIME_WAIT socket connections running Redis

Tags: c, redis

We're using Redis for monitoring on a high traffic web application.
The app is written in c  and uses the credis client
library.

We're seeing enormous numbers of TIME_WAIT connections left over from
our communications with Redis:

$ netstat -a | grep 6379 | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l
15865

Any idea what's going on here?

"

> rh = credis_connect(NULL, 6379, 2000);
>
> credis_incr(rh, "hhhh2",NULL);
>
> credis_close(rh);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SO question #337115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337115/setting-time-wait-tcp) for approaches to this problem.

(I prefer making the client close the connection so the client ends up in the TIME_WAIT state.)