# What are the disadvantages of fastcgi for high performance websites?

Tags: fastcgi

I have read comments that fastcgi is not a good choice for high performance websites:

[nginx, fastcgi and open sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616601/nginx-fastcgi-and-open-sockets)

What specifically makes it a poor choice? What other solutions (the thread above suggests shared memory or building HTTP support into the application directly) might be superior and why?

Comment: dev time is all I can think of.  my cheap vps processes in no time now with fastcgi++

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy, the link I posted specifically references the performance aspects of FCGI (being poor).  While I'm sure that a shared memory approach would be faster (and definitely more complex), I'd love to better understand what specifically about FCGI causes poor performance.  Perhaps it's just the extra buffer copying?

Comment: Hmm, maybe they're talking about server-side scripting sites.  Going 100% ajax relieved a ton of pressure on my php & .net sites.  I'm just now getting into websockets & webworkers, but it's looking like that will relieve pressure even more.  I'm sorry I can't add anything to the hard core http stuff tho :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences and uses between WSGI, CGI, FastCGI, and mod\_python in regards to Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937224/differences-and-uses-between-wsgi-cgi-fastcgi-and-mod-python-in-regards-to-py)