# python socket redirect server - socket.error: (98, 'Address already in use')

Tags: python, sockets

i have this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import select
import time
import sys

buffer_size = 4096
delay = 0.0002
forward_to = ('127.0.0.1', 8888)

class Forward:
    def __init__(self):
        self.forward = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.forward.connect((host, port))
            return self.forward
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return False

class TheServer:
    input_list = []
    channel = {}

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        self.server.listen(200)

    def main_loop(self):
        self.input_list.append(self.server)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(delay)
            ss = select.select
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])
            for self.s in inputready:
                if self.s == self.server:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break

                self.data = self.s.recv(buffer_size)
                if len(self.data) == 0:
                    self.on_close()
                    break
                else:
                    self.on_recv()

    def on_accept(self):
        forward = Forward().start(forward_to[0], forward_to[1])
        clientsock, clientaddr = self.server.accept()
        if forward:
            print clientaddr, "has connected"
            self.input_list.append(clientsock)
            self.input_list.append(forward)
            self.channel[clientsock] = forward
            self.channel[forward] = clientsock
        else:
            print "Can't establish connection with remote server.",
            print "Closing connection with client side", clientaddr
            clientsock.close()

    def on_close(self):
        #print self.s.getpeername(), "has disconnected"
        self.input_list.remove(self.s)
        self.input_list.remove(self.channel[self.s])
        out = self.channel[self.s]
        self.channel[out].close()
        self.channel[self.s].close()
        del self.channel[out]
        del self.channel[self.s]

    def on_recv(self):
        data = self.data
        #print data
        self.channel[self.s].send(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        server = TheServer('', 1080)
        try:
            server.main_loop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Ctrl C - Stopping server"
            sys.exit(1)
        except:
            pass
```

working, problem is give this error every 2-3 minutes and close the script :

```
('79.36.77.61', 58701) has connected
('79.36.77.61', 58702) has connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".redirect2.py", line 82, in ?
    server = TheServer('', 1080)
  File ".redirect2.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.server.bind((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: (98, 'Address already in use')
```

how can i resolve this problem ? im try whit and not working :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            server = TheServer('', 1080)
            server.main_loop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Ctrl C - Stopping server"
            sys.exit(1)
        except:
            pass
```

whit this solution scipt go in crash :(, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your server is crashing and trying to reconnect. The previous connexion is in [TIME_WAIT state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337137/956660). If you want to reuse the address add the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option before binding the socket.

Comment: how can add the SO_REUSEADDR ? im a bigginer in python !